# What does Failed building wheel for Pillow mean?

Tags: python, easyocr

I don't understand what this error 'Failed building wheel for Pillow' means?
I just wanted to install easyocr, but it gives me an error, I tried to find a solution to the problem on the Internet but could not find it. Help me solve this problem, I will be very grateful

```
pip install easyocr
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with opencv. I've removed that tag. do not apply tags that have no relation to the issue.

Comment: Building a wheel is python-speak for compiling the code from form source code in C. Did you install the required compiler? My strong recommendation is to use conda to install Python on a Windows machine. conda will install and configure the compiler for you automatically, resulting is much simplified configuration, and successful pip installs.

Comment: Did you try running `pip install pillow`? Also, what is your OS architecture? Is it 32 bit or 64 bit?
Assuming it is 64 bit, please check if you have installed 64 bit version of Python.

Comment: @Arjun Panicker Yes, I have the 64-bit version of Python installed.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing `pip install -U pip`

This will upgrade the version of pip in your system. Sometimes, the latest version of a python package that you are trying to install is not compatible with the `pip` version installed in the system.

The above command will update your `pip` and once that is done, you can try running the command `pip install easyocr` once again.

Let me know if this helped!!

If this did not help, please let me know whether you are on a windows machine or a linux machine.

If you are on an Ubuntu machine then you probably have to redo the steps that I mentioned using `pip3` instead of `pip`.

Comment: Did not help. I am working on a Windows machine.